# Google App Engine page URL goes to 404 page instead of index page

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have a Node JS web application deployed with Google App Engine.  When I navigate to the page URL:

https://outdoor-activity-finder.appspot.com

after a delay, the 404 page for the website loads.  If I go to:

https://outdoor-activity-finder.appspot.com/

The index page loads and the website works as expected.  Do I need to specify that the default route for the app is '/'?

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs8
env_variables:
  databasePassword: ""
  googleAPIKey: ""
  googleMapsAPIKey: ""
  openWeatherAPIKey: ""
  trailAPIKey: ""
  state: "production"
```

Comment: I am checking your links, and both seems to work and go to the same page, so I understand that you solved the issue. Can you share how?

Comment: Actually I didn't do anything.  Maybe it was a DNS issue on Google's end that resolved itself?